# Selection rules. Transitions due to perturbation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, perturbation-theory

I am working through some worked examples and I am a bit confused by the following exercise:

Consider the hydrogen atom. We apply a time dependent electric field along $z$ such that the perturbation is
$$ \Delta V = -ezE_z(t),\qquad E_z(t) = E_0\exp\left[-\left(\frac{t}{\tau}\right)\right]$$

Assume that at $t=0$ the hydrogen atom was in the ground state $\left|\psi\right> = \left|n=1, l=0, m=0, s_z=+1/2\right>$

Compute the probability of the transition due to the perturbation $\Delta V$ to all possible states with principal quantum numbers $n=2$ and $n=3$. Neglect the fine structure in these computations.

The worked solution I was given starts with:

From selection rules we conclude that the transitions occur to
$$\left|\psi_1\right> = \left|n=2, l=1, m=0, s_z=+1/2\right>$$
$$\left|\psi_2\right> = \left|n=3, l=1, m=0, s_z=+1/2\right>$$

**My Question:**

What about the states:
$$\left|\psi_3\right> = \left|n=2, l=1, m=-1, s_z=+1/2\right>$$
$$\left|\psi_4\right> = \left|n=2, l=1, m=1, s_z=+1/2\right>$$
$$\left|\psi_5\right> = \left|n=3, l=1, m=-1, s_z=+1/2\right>$$
$$\left|\psi_6\right> = \left|n=3, l=1, m=1, s_z=+1/2\right>$$

These also satisfy the selection rules $\Delta l = \pm 1$ and $\Delta m = -1, 0, 1$. Is this just a mistake in the notes I am following? Or is there any reason for these states to not satisfy selection rules?

Comment: You need to consider that your electric field only has a $z$ component. Try working out the selection rule for a transition of the type $\langle n,l,m|z|n',l',m'\rangle.$